Does Windows 10's portability limit OS features?
From what I can see Windows 10 can support 2015 CPUs, and I'm aware that all x86 architecture uses similar intruction sets, but surely there's features that are missing if it supports that many older CPUs don't have available, such as instruction set extensions like AVX. Would it be a much faster OS if it supported way less CPUs? How come it still supports CPUs that old and how does it support them?

It is quite customary to have multiple implementations of a performance critical algorithm optimized for different feature levels. You then check which features are available and jump to the right implementation. This has a minimal overhead if done right and can work around such problems. Not sure if the Kernel has much need for that though. For functional things such as additional security features, this is more complicated though.

"Surely there's features that are missing if it supports that many older CPUs don't have available, such as instruction set extensions like AVX." - Every processor that supports running Windows 10 supports AVX.  AVX has been supported longer then Windows 10 has existed.

Iterative degeneration as well. See also: Windows 8; Windows 10 Lock Screen adverts; upcoming Windows 11 Start Menu banner ads; forced updates; forced use of AI; forced use of online accounts et al.

@Ramhound Technically Windows 10 runs on CPUs that predate/lack AVX, and it was never called out as a required feature. It's only quite recent (since the Win11 release, funnily enough) that Microsoft has actually published specific supported CPU lists.

It’s not required and I only mentioned AVX since it was mentioned of course AVX was actually removed from the current generation of Intel processors oddly enough.

@Ramhound AVX/AVX2 are still supported in the current gen, as will further extensions into the future (AVX-VNNI, AVX10, etc.). It was only AVX512 that was removed (because the little cores didn't support it, and it was rarely used & not very useful for the vast majority of client computing).

Windows 10 is also portable to completely different architectures: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/overview ; the parts of it deep in the core that are built around NT will probably port cleanly to any "normal" 32 bit or 64 bit processor.

Quite awhile ago it used to be the case that a core library used by the kernel for synchronization operations had two different versions: One for use with computers that had more than one CPU (this was before cores, this was actual CPUs), and one for computers (most desktops!) that had only one.  Thus optimizing for each case.  The CPU count was determined during installation and the proper library was installed.  Later this became more dynamic (IIRC).


Would it be a much faster OS if it supported way less CPUs?

Speaking from experience as somebody who builds their entire operating system from scratch, no, it would not be ‘much faster’. A few percent at most for the cases where it mattered, and no difference at all in a vast majority of the code. I’ve actually bench-marked this on relatively recent hardware (an AMD Zen 2 system), and the difference between building for a generic target (essentially the original x86-64 spec from 2000) and building for the specific hardware was less than 1% for a majority of things other than highly performance intensive things such as multimedia transcoding, encryption, data compression, and cross-architecture full-system emulation.
There are effectively three ways that a program might take advantage of ‘new’ instructions:

Explicit usage via inline assembly. This is how a lot of cryptography and multi8media encoding/decoding stuff does it, the general parts of the code call out to hand-written manually optimized implementations of the performance sensitive parts, which usually use special instructions. This is usually the biggest bang for your buck, but is also the hardest to implement, and it’s super specific to the particular algorithm. Encryption, compression, and other very large scale bulk data transformation operations benefit from this, possibly a lot, but they’re about the only things that can.
Implicit usage via autodetection in the compiler. The canonical example of this is the POPCNT instruction on x86 (you can find a nice write-up on what this does and why it matters here: https://vaibhavsagar.com/blog/2019/09/08/popcount/). GCC, Clang, and pretty much all other modern compilers are smart enough to detect most manual implementations of the operation this instruction does, and will simply replace the manual implementation with a call to the instruction. This can have a significant performance impact, but it’s often not in a performance-critical piece of code unless it’s a part of something that would benefit from a well written inline assembly implementation.
Indirect usage via auto-vectorization. There are some cases where a given CPU can perform a given operation on multiple instances of data in parallel. AVX and SSE provide lots of ways to do this for example. Auto-vectorization in the compiler can detect some instances where such instructions could be used, and then simplify the loops in the code to use them. This also can often provide a significant performance benefit, but it requires a lot of constraints to be met for it to work well (if at all), and it’s actually not exceptionally common in a lot of code for those constraints to be met. Simulations, games, and similar things typically see a lot of benefit from this, but many other things don’t.

None of these typically have a major impact on basic ‘OS’ code outside of a few very specific places. Those places are often very performance critical, but the performance difference is often small enough that most users won’t ever notice it.
The place where they truly have a big impact is very specific user workloads. But that rarely has to do with the OS, it’s usually application software, and even there it’s often a small part of the application, not the whole thing.

How come it still supports CPUs that old

Money. Typical hardware lifecycle at big enterprises (that is, the people who MS actually makes significant money off of) are usually at least 5 years long, and that’s if they’re properly staying on top of lifecycle management for their hardware. 10, 15, or even 20 year lifecycles are not unusual, and I have personally decommissioned systems older than I was at the time on multiple occasions.
If all your major customers are still using 5-10 year old hardware, you keep supporting that hardware until they stop using it, or you start losing money.
Also, it’s actually easier to some extent to continue to support old x86 systems. Doing so involves simpler code, and simpler code is almost always more reliable and easier to maintain.

and how does it support them?

Very easily. You almost always have to opt-in to any ‘new’ functionality, a typical compiler building 64-bit x86 executables will spit out code that will run on an original AMD K8 Opteron from 2003, or if not then something not much newer (the most recent ‘default’ target I’ve seen is about 2008 hardware). From that point, the only issue with supporting old hardware is dealing with hardware bugs (see the Pentium F00F bug for a rather famous example from the 32-bit x86 era).
You can opt in to newer things if you want, and smart software often does. There’s a couple of ways to do that. The naive approach, typically taken by most user software, is to inspect the CPU at startup (usually by calling CPUID on x86 systems) and then branch based on that info to select the code to use. The smarter approach, used at least by the Linux kernel, is to similarly inspect the CPU at startup, and then hot-patch the code to only use the desired code paths.

Win10 did drop support for older CPUs without 128-bit Lock-CompareSwap instruction, this is used for implementing multi-threading synchronization primitives, and before this, Windows used 64-bit and 32-bit variants of this instruction. So yes, Windows has incentive to drop support for older CPUs.
However, the AVX feature you mentioned, it's not the main problem - Newer OSes just need to be able to save and restore those registers when switching execution context, so if your OS only understands AVX (or even SSE), AVX-512 will not be usable in newer applications.
Lastly, I think it's not portability that Windows mainly concerns, Windows is a widely used system, and unlike macOS where Apple keeps deprecating old and introducing new APIs, Windows APIs must be stable for decades without breaking bug compatibility! (Yes, bug compatibility is an actual thing.)

obligatory XKCD on the bug compatibility: https://xkcd.com/1172/ :)


Would it be a much faster OS if it supported way less CPUs?

Impossible to tell from the outside, but you can take a look at the "x86-64-v3" efforts that some Linux distributions are doing – it is going to be roughly the same. (The "v2" and "v3" indicate different levels of CPU features, e.g. I think v3 implies AVX support among several other things.)

https://sunnyflunk.github.io/2023/01/15/x86-64-v3-Mixed-Bag-of-Performance.html
https://www.phoronix.com/review/ubuntu-x86-64-v3-benchmark
https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2024/01/02/exploring-x86-64-v3-red-hat-enterprise-linux-10


How come it still supports CPUs that old and how does it support them?

Compilers usually have options to adjust what machine code they generate. For example, GCC has -march=, -mtune=, and similar options that can be used when compiling C files; so if you want to compile a program so that it'll run without SSE2 you can just tell GCC to do that. (MSVC and Clang have similar options.) This of course gives you the slowest, "lowest denominator" output but it's very simple to achieve.
Additionally, when a program runs on the actual CPU, it can use the cpuid CPU instruction in its code to check what features that specific CPU is capable of – and depending on the result, it may switch between differently-compiled versions of the same function; e.g. the input .c file may have a "matrix multiply" function that the compiler automatically duplicates into "basic", "SSE2", "AVX", etc. versions to be selected at run time. This lets you get "best of the both worlds" but requires a bit more work upfront, so it's usually done only where it matters.
I've also seen a middle-ground approach where the entire .c file was compiled twice, once into "foo_AVX2.dll" and again into "foo_noAVX.dll", with the program using CPUID to decide which one to load on startup.

It would possibly technically be faster if it supported fewer CPU's, but it would likely not make a discernible difference (ie a fraction of a percent if its done right)
There would not be features missing to support older CPU's, rather there might be different modules/algorythms or code blocks which would be called or executed depending on the CPU functionality.   By way of an example, if the CPU supports AES-NI, use that for handling AES encryption or decryption, but if its missing use a slower software based call.   In some cases there is no software equivalent to the firmware equivalent - in which case the OS would just return an error that that call is invalid.
I'm a lot more familiar with Linux then Windows - and while I expect the mechanism are different, the logic on how to support older CPUs is likely  similar.  Linux does this by having a relatively small core for the OS, and make extensive use of modules to enable additional functionality.  (In many ways, a module is similar to a driver - so you have drivers to extend hardware support).
AFAICT Windows 11 could also work fine with older CPU's then those it works with - all you need to do is work around the requirement to support TPM (for security like bitlocker) and disable the arbitrary check/cut-off.

Yeah - even Windows 11 can run on a CPU from 2006 - https://www.techradar.com/news/windows-11-runs-on-pc-with-ancient-single-core-intel-pentium-4-cpu - this may be interesting because it add strength to the argument that if reducing the supported CPUs could speed up the OS then Microsoft would have had good reason for doing so, being that they artificially put a roadblock up to stop systems older then about 2017 working - and it might have provided a compelling reason for people to upgrade.

"It would possibly technically be faster if it supported fewer CPU's" - Why?  If Windows requires say x86-64-v3, then by extension it supports all features of previous x86-64 microarchitecture levels.  The only way you would get any improvement is to create a new microarchitecture level that has fewer features.  Less silicon would make the entire 86-64 architecture faster. Windows wouldn't see any performance improvements as long as it pulls in specific x86 extensions when it's compiled.

@ramhound Because of fewer checks to see if instructions are available and less memory used by the same so a tiny amount more available.

I don't believe you would see any measurable performance gains from not making those instruction checks.

@ramhound agreed - that is why I stated "technically faster" and "won't make a discernible difference" and "fraction of a percent"

@Ramhound: If a new microarchitecture level has new features that let the CPU do certain things much quicker and more efficiently than older CPUs could, then tailoring Windows to only support the very newest CPUs would allow it to use these new, fast instructions for stuff that Windows versions that have to also be able to run on older CPUs have to implement in older, slower fashion.

Aren't the strict requirements for hardware and software one of the major reasons why MacOS is much more performant? I have that impression because it's something one of my lecturers said and something I see answered (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440577/why-apple-os-software-and-so-many-things-are-highly-stable-and-smooth) when I look up the reasons why MacOS is faster than Windows and most modern OSes.

@WaveCave I don't believe that hardware restrictions combined with software is a major reason MacOS is more performant.  Linux is also way more performant then Windows while supporting a vast array of hardware - Windows is just badly written.  It is also very arguable that MacOS is faster then Windows - indeed my searching tells me for many use cases Windows is faster then MAC on the same hardware.

“more performant” - What does that mean? Windows and macOS handle devices and drivers differently. However, when macOS ran on x86 hardware, the performance gap came from those differences not because strict hardware requirements. Your lecturer doesn’t sound knowledgeable at all.

My suspicion is that this is about Spectre/Meltdown mitigations -- these make quite a difference in performance. "Less silicon" was the idea behind Itanium, that is not a commercially viable approach even if technically sound.


How come it still supports CPUs that old and how does it support them?

It still supports old CPUs because a lot of them exist and people are using them.

How does it support them?

This is over simplified but...
If AVX supported then
{
run code A}
else
  {run code B}
}

Now in most cases the B code path is slower and because it requires more lines of code to create a replacement function.
You can replace most CPU feature with a block of code like the above "if" statement.
The problem is the more code B paths there are will slow down your OS, and eventually it will become too slow to use for any practical work.

if (feature supported) set function x address to code path f; would be more accurate. In simple terms, program runs this logic once at startup, and then just call functions like nothing happened. Thus, only supporting a small set of CPU's (those specifically having feature) and dropping this decision code would speed up the execution of your program by all of 3 CPU cycles. Total. Is it worth it? When your entire startup code alone runs thousands of instructions? And if that code is in a shared library loaded once at system startup and never unloaded, the difference become laughable.

Laughable unmeasurable given the number of instructions per second the processor can handle at startup. I mean essentially have Windows devices that startup within 3-5 seconds. After that happens the kernel has done most of it’s hard work.

There are some (optional) OS features that depend on specific CPU features for any reasonable implementation. It's not just the core compute instruction sets that matter.
A couple of examples:

Hyper-V requires hardware virtualisation support and Second-Level Address Translation (SLAT).
WSL2 runs on the Hyper-V hypervisor and has the same requirement.
Virtualisation-Based Security (VBS) ditto.

This also includes Hypervisor-Protected Code Integrity (HVCI) / memory integrity.
A CPU that supports Mode-Based Execution Control (MBEC) is required to run this at full performance. The software-based fallback can have a performance penalty of up to 40% (!!).
MBEC support is likely responsible for Windows 11's supported CPU list. Those 2015 Skylake CPUs support AVX ... but not MBEC.




There are ways to make code compatible when it's run on old hardware and fast when run on new hardware. The most trivial way to do this is to just compile multiple versions of the app and detect the correct one at runtime. More commonly, you let the compiler generate multiple implementations for certain performance critical operations and select the correct one at runtime, resulting in less binary bloat compared to having 2 whole copies of the software.
It's important to take the human into consideration with this question though. If Microsoft has a company-wide mandate that says "all parts of Windows must support every x86_64 processor ever made", lots of non-performance-critical code isn't going to be optimized. Programmers are just going to design for the lowest common denominator. Consider the issue where Discord just recently quit shipping the 32-bit build by default. For the past few years, squeezing that extra bit of performance out of a chat app didn't justify the complexity of trying to detect and install the best version.
By comparison, if Microsoft's official policy is "we only support x86-64-v3 or better", the compiler team can focus their efforts on newer processors, the kernel team can design around newer primitives, the guy programming some random system utility can set -march=x86-64-v3. Will he? Maybe.
How much does this all really matter? It's impossible to know. Probably not much.

Lots of smarter people than me have commented here, but I think that one more thing can be said:
The new instructions aren't really all that important from an OS performance point of view.
They are mostly concerned with multimedia applications and enable faster gaming or video processing, and maybe a bit of cryptography, but that's not the main job of an OS. The OS itself is mostly concerned with process and memory management. The GUI layer might take a bit of advantage of additional graphics power, but then again it's simple enough that the existing instructions already satisfy those needs well enough.
The basic x86/x64 instruction set has been stable for decades now and that's really all that the OS needs. Speedups in modern processors come from a more efficient execution of these old instructions rather than new instructions.
Now, I think that in the past decade there have been some innovations regarding virtualization and security, allowing the OS to better isolate processes and even kernel mode drivers - that would be a reason to drop support for older CPUs (and in fact that's what Windows 11 did, although the restriction is a bit artifical since you can force it to run on older CPUs). But it won't affect performance much.

Many others have explained the "how", I'll focus a bit on the "why".
Microsoft is trying to sell as many copies of their OS as possible. Supporting a larger number of CPUs means you have a larger number of potential customers.  Many people aren't going to go buy a new PC just for your fancy new OS.  You can either support their existing machine and maybe sell them a new OS license, or drop support and not make a dime until they replace their hardware years down the road.
Another aspect of this is the "embedded" or "IoT" build of Windows.  This is a special edition that's designed to be installed on single-purpose computer systems that are embedded inside a larger machine (like the computer that runs the interface on an ATM, or that controls a MRI scanner's hardware).  These computer systems cannot be replaced or upgraded freely. They may not be removable at all, or if they are they may not be upgradeable without forcing the entire device to go through long, expensive regulatory and certification processes all over again.  Normal desktop PCs will put out a new generation of hardware every 12-18 months, but hardware and software for embedded applications might be manufactured and supported for a decade or longer (I saw one embedded computer design celebrate its 40th birthday).  If you drop support for slightly older hardware, there's a real risk that it's faster and cheaper for customers to re-write their software for a competitor's OS. I'm certainly not going to hire a submarine to go dig my data recorder off the ocean floor so I can rebuild it with a new computer system just because Microsoft doesn't think my CPU is cool any more. You'd need an overwhelmingly justifiable reason to drop support for older devices, and a performance boost isn't close.
